# Github pull remote repo without commiting

Tags: git, version-control, github

I was working on a project in a certain directory that was linked to it's corresponding remote git repo, but I had to copy the contents of the project to a different folder, and now need to relink it to the remote repo.

Everything I see says to do...

```
cd newfolder
git init
git add -A
git commit -a -m "Creating repo"
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git
```

... but I want to pull the latest changes of the remote project, and don't want to push my local repo. Will the above do that for me, or is there something else I can do?

Comment: That seems a bit much... I would have thought you would only need to do `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/reponame.git` or something along those lines.

Comment: (I am unsure, that's why I left it as a comment, not an answer.  I'm busy with a few things right now, so I can't verify.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just

```
cd newfolder
git clone git@github.com:username/reponame.git .
```

Comment: @yiati ... or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Cloning into a non-empty directory will not work: `fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Comment: Chowlett you understood correctly, and Klas you are correct but I just deleted the contents of the new folder and ran a clone so this is what I wanted. I was overthinking what I was wanted to do :P

Answer (score 0):

Just creating a completely new repository using `git init` will not work as this will start a completely new tree of commits, which will completely different from everything known by your remote repository.

Do you have any new changes in your separate directory?

If you did simply copy the directory and did not change anything, just delete the whole directory and clone your remote repository again, and everything is fine.

If you have important changes in your private copy, it probably gets tricky to get them integrated correctly in the remote repository. - But also in this case the first step is to get a clone of the repository to get all the history and all the new changes.